# Ubuntu Phone won't download system update

Tags: ubuntu-touch, update-manager

My Bq Ubuntu Phone offers me Version 20 system update, but when I click the "Install..." button nothing happens. Sometimes it flashes a progress indicator with 0% for a fraction of a second. Anyone with the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was some kind of a UI bug as rebooting the device resulted in progress indicator to be visible but stuck at 0%. It apparently still downloads the update, and install it after re-starting the phone.